# Что необходимо для создания игры на Python с возможностью играть по сети?

Tags: python, разработка-игр

Имеется некоторое подобие игры на Python. Что необходимо, что бы можно было создать возможность играть по сети, к примеру, как в Майнкрафт?

Необходимо ли создавать для этого сайт? Или можно обойтись без него (вписал айпишник и играй с соседом)?

Comment: Ничего не необходимо, кроме поддержки сети в самой игре, а там уже вписывайте айпишники как хотите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от того, как реализована поддержка сетевой игры.

Если в игру (код, который бдут запускать игроки) заложена поддержка запуска сервера, то любой игрок сможет поднять сервер, и любые другие игроки смогут подключиться к этому человеку (при условии доступности этого IP-адреса - т.е. должны находиться в одной локальной сети, или сервер должен быть со статическим открытым IP-адресом, или ...)

С учетом того, что игра написана на Python, отдавать всем подряд исходники серверной части небезопасно (привет, читерство).

Если же игра не умеет поднимать локальный сервер, то достаточно сервера (можно виртуального), на котором будет крутиться серверная часть игры, и к которой будут подключаться игроки.
Веб-хостинг для этого, как таковой, не нужен, если зарегистрироваться, сменить ник-пароль-емейл и всё такое прочее можно из самой игры.

Сайт будет удобен как минимум, если игрок забыл свой пароль или хочет сделать что-нибудь (сменить никнейм или пароль, например), не запуская саму игру.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого следует прежде всего написать саму игру. Затем встанут два вопроса: на каком хостинге её разместить, и где взять столько денег.

Comment: а без хостинга игра по сети работать не будет? КС же шел по локалке и по инету вреде не должен использовать хостинг.

Comment: Во-первых, писать игру надо с оглядкой на мультиплеер. А во-вторых, хостинг и деньги для мультиплеера желательны, но совершенно не обязательны.